# GIT pull just the project files without pulling the LFS module

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I have a bitbucket project, which has an integrated LFS module too. I had confirmed that the files expected to be in LFS module are present in LFS module itself and not within the main project.

But when I clone the project, this is what is happening:

```
Cloning into 'testing'...
remote: Counting objects: 310, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (164/164), done.
remote: Total 310 (delta 124), reused 219 (delta 104)
Receiving objects: 100% (310/310), 25.57 MiB | 846.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (124/124), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Downloading xxx1.file (60.16 MB)
Downloading xxx2.file (61.16 MB)
Downloading xxx3.file (62.16 MB)
Downloading xxx4.file (63.16 MB)
```

The LFS files also gets downloaded together when using the 'git clone' command. If I try to stop the downloading abruptly, then most of the files  in the git repo gets deleted locally and shows this on 'git status':

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    .gitattributes
    deleted:    .gitignore
```

How to avoid 'git lfs pull' from happening, when using 'git clone' command?

**GIT LFS ENV:**

```
git-lfs/2.1.0 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.8; git bd2c9987)
git version 1.9.1

Endpoint=REMOTE/info/lfs (auth=basic)
LocalWorkingDir=LOCAL
LocalGitDir=LOCAL/.git
LocalGitStorageDir=LOCAL/.git
LocalMediaDir=LOCAL/.git/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=LOCAL/.git/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
AccessDownload=basic
AccessUpload=basic
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

Comment: But isn't this exactly what should happen? Either `git clone` or `git lfs clone` - in any way it seems that files are downloaded initially, just faster with second command. . https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs#clone-respository Or maybe actually need something like https://github.com/Microsoft/GVFS

Comment: This is exactly what should happen for some users. For others its got to be different. Else I could have avoided LFS and pushed everything to repo directly. Also I feel, there should be something, that could be done to avoid this 'git lfs pull' from happening automatically.

Comment: I didn't mean `should happen` in context some users or others, rather that this is how the command works. Any way I see your point. IF the GVFS is not an option, then maybe try a sparse checkout. Init empty folder, add a remote, and do a sparse checkout. Actually here is one nice answer on that https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233327/is-it-possible-to-clone-only-part-of-a-git-project

Comment: setting the different paths for all the files present in lfs is going to be painstaking. I am more interested in changing something in the git config, which stops the automatic download of lfs files. Thanks for the suggestions! Will consider them as a secondary option.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is the answer you need ( hope the answer is not too late :) ): `git lfs install --skip-smudge`

> --skip-smudge: Skips automatic downloading of objects on clone or pull. This requires a manual "git lfs pull" every time a new commit is checked out on your repository.

[more details](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/5703b808220103063ededf5c6149c93201be9e07/docs/man/git-lfs-install.1.ronn#L36-L39)